# What is the command to make a command block emit a redstone signal after 20 mins

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I make a command block emit a redstone signal after 20 mins. I want it to emit a  redstone signal after 20 mins to power another command block that will have /tp to send all players to a certain area. It will also need some thing that resets it to 20 mins

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MGNWAXIKoU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to pause a command block in vanilla Minecraft. I haven't yet played it, but I *believe* you could accomplish this pretty simply using [ComputerCraft](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/forum/12-programs/), if installing some mods would work for whatever you're doing. An easier option, as imulsion points out, would be using the timer IC from RedPower.

Otherwise, since you need exactly 20 minutes, you could use a couple of daylight sensors (one wired up to be a [nighttime sensor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xI0FucxTrdY)) with some non-sticky pistons to push some blocks to handle this. It doesn't have to be a very large or complicated clock.

Comment: I should point out that it would be much easier to use RedPower rather than ComputerCraft, as the built-in timer integrated circuit is simple and does not require you to program computers

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to have a command block summon an Item entity with an age of minus 15 minutes on top of a pressure plate on a block on which a redstone torch is attached to.

The item will despawn in 20 minutes, depowering the block and turning the redstone torch on.

Comment: Xisuma recently covered this in a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AK7fSfK46s

Answer (score 5):

You will actually need to build a redstone timer that takes 20 minutes to output a signal. There was a recommendation for a /wait command, however, it was not implemented. There are plenty of delay timer designs you can look in to though. I have also included a link to the official commands list.

Recommendation for /wait: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1962496-wait-command-command-block-only-cut-down-curcuits/

The full list of commands is available here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands